date format in YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ssZ
Currently i am having date in the format 2024-06-12 12:24:06.157
But i need the change in
2035-12-11T19:28:00Z this format.
Can anyone help me on this ?
is there any function for this to do it ?
I tried with date format function but not able to achieve the same.

Please post the code you tried.

and tag the platform that you're on

If you are using python
from datetime import datetime

your_date_str = "2024-06-12 12:24:06.157"

# set date str with your current format
dt = datetime.strptime(your_date_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

# set date str with your expected format
new_date_str = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')


Thnx for your reply.  Actually the Tool on which i work does not support python. is there a way it can be done in a single line code using any function like. Date_Parse, etc.

@Rajat What language are you using? Please post any code snippets you have tried, so we can help you
